# Why has Elasticsearch put a limit of 1000 on number of fields

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

1. Why has Elasticsearch put a limit of 1000 on the total number of fields?
2. Will it cause any degradation in performance?
3. If it will, why? There is no such limit in lucene.

Also, can someone please explain these settings more in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the [explanation from the documentation itself](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings) is pretty good when it comes to these settings.

There are situation where the mapping of indices is dynamic (logging use cases usually or some rogue documents generator in the users' infrastructure) and having it like this could lead to hundreds of thousands of fields in indices. When this usually happens, only a handful of documents have values in those gazillion fields, while most of the documents don't. This, from the disk usage point of view, is not a great thing. Why this could be a problem, again is very well explained in [another section of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/general-recommendations.html#sparsity).

The bad part, though, is that most of the times the users didn't plan or didn't expect to have such a high number of fields and the **soft** limit we introduced for fields count is to protect users in these scenarios from hurting themselves unintentionally.

If you have a well thought mapping for your indices and you know those 1000 fields limit is not for you, you can change it to a number that fits your use case and scenario:

`PUT /test/_settings
{
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 2000
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Also can you please explain this answer as according to this fields above 1000 can be harmful?
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/maximum-number-of-fields-in-an-index-mapping/90150/2

Comment: Yeah, those are valid very good reasons too. What I mentioned in my reply is the most common, easier to investigate and explain, with most visible impact. In the past, when we introduced doc-values as the default, users would complain about disk usage going up after upgrade. Depending on the use case (hardware used, use case specifics) an user can benefit from tidying his/her mappings following my and Zach's suggestions, but it's not easy to assess the improvements. The disk usage, though, might be easier to observe.